# Unit testing a void method with a background worker that calls another method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, refactoring

Keep in mind that I'm pretty new to unit testing so please bear with me.  I have a method that uses a background worker to call a method whose class in another project in my solution, and I'm finding a hard time trying to wrap my brain around unit testing it.

Here is basically what the method is doing:

```
public void VerifyLocation()
{
    this.IsBusy = true;

    using (BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker())
    {
        worker.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Context context = Profile.GetContext();

            AssetManagerService svc = new AssetManagerService(context);
            this.Status = svc.Login();

            if (this.Status == AssetManagerLoginStatus.Success)
            {
                //Do stuff
                this.ShowError = false;
            }
            else if (this.Status == AssetManagerLoginStatus.LocationDoesNotExst || this.Status == AssetManagerLoginStatus.LibraryTitleNotDetermined)
                this.ShowError = true;
            else
                this.ShowError = false;
        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                this.ShowError = true;
            }

            this.IsBusy = false;
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of what `AssetManagerService` looks like:

```
public class AssetManagerService
{
    //AssetManager is an abstract class
    private AssetManager provider = null;

    public AssetManagerService(UnityContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.InitializeProvider();
    }

    private void InitializeProvider()
    {
        //Determine provider based on Context properties
    }

    public AssetManagerLoginStatus Login()
    {
        return this.provider.Login();
    }
}
```

Obviously what I care about most is that the `Login()` method was called.  Would I use a `Shim` to control what happens during `DoWork`?  Would I use a `Stub` to force `Login()` to return a specific value?  Both concepts are pretty new to me.  Does refactoring need to be done to make it more unit testable?  If so, what changes would need to be made?

Comment: What is the edition of Visual Studio that you use? seems like a good candidate for MS Fakes.

Answer (score 0):

I would move DoWork to a separate method because it's much easier to test it that way than trying to test asynchronous/multithreaded code.

If you just need to test if the Login is called a mock/shim is probably the way to go. Also it would be easier to inject a AssetManager mock through the constructor into the AssetManagerService instance.

Besides it's easier to mock interfaces. Maybe you can extract an interface from AssetManager, mock it and inject it through the constructor into the AssetManagerInstance. To mock an interface you don't necessarily need a shim. A simpler mocking framework like NSubstitute would do the job. With NSubstitute you can also tell your mock to return a specific value when Login() is called.